# customize redirect of password reset in laravel based on table field user type laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, passwords, laravel-5.8

i have normal users and admin users in project
i have implemented password reset in normal user area.i have used same for admin password reset
but i want to redirect to admin login form if password reset done by admin user
my user table have user_type 1 for admin user.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/login';  // this is redirection to user login

    
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {


     $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

how i wll get email id of who password done reset here, so i can make redirect on condition basis